# Need to read records from a kafka topic and once 50 records are read call an API that accepts 50 records in a single request

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to read records from a Kafka topic and once 50 records are read call an API that accepts 50 records in a single request.

Any suggestions how to implement it when the application doesn't have any database for storage?

I'm able to read records from the Kafka topic, looking for recommendations on how to queue the records until the count reaches 50.

Comment: The application is a spring boot application using spring kafka to consume records from the topic.

Comment: have you considered kafka stream?

Answer (score 0):

Set `max.poll.records=50` for the consumer.

> max.poll.records: The maximum number of records returned in a single
>   call to poll().

I don't know how frequent you receive data, if you see that batches have less than 50 records, try to increase `session.timeout.ms` (default is 10 seconds).

Read more about consumer configuration in [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)